# How to test for Bioelecetrical impedance in an body fat analysier

Tags: impedance

I have an interesting project for school. I want to test these body fat machines for consistency between different brands. Ultimately to see if a cheaper brand is as good as an expensive one. 
http://www.drgrab.com.au/products/handheld-body-fat-analyzer?utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=googlepla&variant=1089145592&gclid=CjwKEAjw96aqBRDNhM6MtJfE-wYSJADiMfgg3iLGVTTN6ccbhbLI3NiCKU8lRDG5K_zzmfkFIP6XshoCU9Lw_wcB
[http://www.amazon.com/Omron-Monitor-model-HBF-306C-Black/dp/B000FYZMYK](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000FYZMYK)

These machines look to use Bioelecetrical impedance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioelectrical_impedance_analysis). Is there some way that I can simulate a person holding the handles? e.g. with a resistor between wires connected to handles.

I want to compare different machines between different companies to see if they give the same results but to do that I think I need a standard testing rig. I could hold the handles myself on different devices but it seems to change during the day. e.g. the morning is lower and the afternoon higher.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the Wikipedia article:

> The impedance of cellular tissue can be modeled as a resistor (representing the extracellular path) in parallel with a resistor and capacitor in series (representing the intracellular path).

Therefore such a network ought to make a reasonable model for your purposes too.

You'll need a way to get some ballpark values for these components; one option would be to use your own impedance analyser on some volunteers to figure out what's reasonable. The literature on this sort of measurement probably has plenty of examples too, however.